# Inserting an image in a GUI using Qt Designer

Tags: qt, qt-designer

I want to know how to insert an image in a GUI using Qt Designer. I am trying to add a logo.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can start inserting a label.

Next, you right click on it an then click "change rich text...".

A new window will pop-up. Click on the figure Icon "Insert figure".

[image: Insert Figure]

Now, you have to create a resource file. Click on the Pencil button.

Next, click on the "New resource file" button.

[image]

Choose a name and a folder (your working directory would be a good choice) to save it.

Now, click on the "Add prefix" button.

[image]

Choose a name for it.

Then, click on the "Add file" button.

[image]

And there you go! Click "OK" and you figure should be there.

Just be aware that you should resize your figure to a proper size before using it.

Answer (score 49):

- Drag and drop your Label on your window
- Select the label, and you'll see on the right side of your screen the 'Property Editor' frame and the 'QLabel' menu.
- Click on pixmap => Choose File, select a file.

[image]

Make sure you have resized it before, you won't be able to do so in Qt Designer.